# Rules for sentences containing lists of things

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> "Symptoms of lactic acid build up in muscles include cramps, spasms,
>   fatigue and sensitivity."

Does "sensitivity" need to be qualified, as in "sensitivity to touch"? Can someone point out the "rules" that come into play here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the following sentence grammatically correct?
>
> "Symptoms of lactic acid build up in muscles include cramps, spasms,
>   fatigue and sensitivity."

Yes, but you should change *build up* to *[buildup](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buildup)*.

> Does "sensitivity" need to be qualified, as in "sensitivity to touch"?

That wouldn't hurt (no pun intended), but it isn't necessary.  You've established *muscles* as the subject.

> Can someone point out the "rules" that come into play here?

Regarding serial commas?  You've broken no rules here.

Answer (score 0):

The following sentence is grammatically correct:

"Symptoms of lactic acid build up in muscles include cramps, spasms, fatigue, and sensitivity."

"Sensitivity" does not need to be qualified, as in "sensitivity to touch".

Correlatively your question (Rules for sentences containing lists of things) there are no special "rules" (worthly to be mentioned) that come into play here, except for serial commas.

Comment: Some style guides, esp. in STM, advise against the use of comma before *and*, irrespective of context.

Comment: In any case, the OP seems to ask about rules in respect of 'sensitivity', whether 'to touch' is required.